# liquibase diff hibernate and jpa models vs an empty database throws could not build classFile

Tags: spring, maven, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

i have a multi microservices project, one microservice is named Foo, under the Foo service pom i added a plugin for liquibase with hibernate like so:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.yaml</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

the liquibase.yaml file looks like this:

```
outputChangeLogFile: src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/2019/changelog-v1.xml
changeLogFile: src/main/resources/liquibase/changelog-master.xml
url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
defaultSchemaName: foo_schema
username: postgres
password: oajmi
driver: org.postgresql.Driver
referenceUrl: hibernate:spring:de.ph.foo.model?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialects
diffChangeLogFile: src/main/resources/liquibase/changelogs/2019/diff-changelog.xml
```

executing `liquibase generateChangeLog` works fine, but `liquibase diff` throws this error:

```
[INFO] --- liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:diff (default-cli) @ foo-service ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
[INFO]   File: src/main/resources/liquibase.yaml
[INFO]   'outputChangeLogFile' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
INFO 17/11/2019 21:48: liquibase-hibernate: Reading hibernate configuration hibernate:spring:de.ph.foo.model?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialects
INFO 17/11/2019 21:48: liquibase-hibernate: Found package de.ph.foo.model
INFO 17/11/2019 21:48: liquibase-hibernate: Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialects
INFO 17/11/2019 21:48: liquibase-hibernate: Found hibernate.enhanced_idfalse
nov. 17, 2019 9:48:43 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
nov. 17, 2019 9:48:43 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
nov. 17, 2019 9:48:43 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
nov. 17, 2019 9:48:43 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.650 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-11-17T21:48:43+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:diff (default-cli) on project mortgage-brokerage-service: Error setting up or running Liquibase: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:diff (default-cli) on project mortgage-brokerage-service: Error setting up or running Liquibase: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error setting up or running Liquibase: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:398)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.execute(LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:143)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.performLiquibaseTask(LiquibaseDatabaseDiff.java:166)
    at org.liquibase.maven.plugins.AbstractLiquibaseMojo.execute(AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java:394)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.spi.ArchiveException: Could not build ClassFile
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.toClassFile(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.handleEntry(ClassFileArchiveEntryHandler.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.archive.internal.JarProtocolArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarProtocolArchiveDescriptor.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.scan(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:57)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase.buildConfigurationFromScanning(HibernateSpringDatabase.java:243)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase.buildConfiguration(HibernateSpringDatabase.java:55)
    at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateDatabase.setConnection(HibernateDatabase.java:46)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(DatabaseFactory.java:131)
    at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:151)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:85)
    ... 25 more
```

I have a hunch that its a package problem but the package name it correct, so whats wrong here?
could anyone please help me?

Comment: I strongly assume there is a version mismatch. As I saw those dependencies was released in 2015. In that ages e.g. the Java8 wasn't fully supported. Another idea is the javassist dependency. Make sure only one javassist dependency there's on the classpath.
BTW do you use those ancient versions on purpose?

Comment: no i am following a guide, i couldnt find a new version

Answer (score 0):

There are newer versions either of the plugin and dependencies as well. Try this (I haven't)

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.yaml</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId> <!-- Pay attention to the artifactId has also changed -->
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

#### UPDATE

1. I need to know more information about that project, e.g. do you use Spring Boot or not if the maven plugin way is needed.
2. AFAIK Liquibase Maven Plugin doesn't require Spring dependencies.
3. Spring has a built-in liquibase support. If you use Spring this way is recommended.

   - [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool)
   - [Step-By-Step Example](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-liquibase-example/)

Comment: this throws: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Comment: yes i use spring and, i need to generate the database scheme from my models against an empty database, thats why i am using this approach, do you have an anlternative recommanded way for doing this?